# dateTtimeZ to date, time

Tags: python, pandas

My data-frame includes a column that contains timestamp values in this (example) format:
`2019-12-31T23:20:10.000Z`

Currently, the type of this column is `object`.

I want to:

**(1)** Convert it to `datetime` type.

**(2)** Split this column into two columns: `date` and `time`, as in this example:

`2019-12-31`

`23:20:10`

**(3)** Take only observations that happened before Dec 15, 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime`

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

For date

```
df['date'] = df.timestamp.dt.date
```

For time

```
df['date'] = df.timestamp.dt.time
```

Filter by timestamp

```
condition = (df.timestamp < '2019-12-15')
sample_df = df[condition].sample(n=2)
```

Faster way if your dataset contains repeated timestamp

```
def memoize_dt(s):
    dates = {date:datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%b-%d-%Y') for date in s.unique()}
    return s.map(dates)
```

Comment: This is the fastest vectorized way.

Comment: For a dataset that large, look at parallel or distributed computing if required. @qwerty